# Pass 2 different kinds of X training data to ML model simultaneously

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm trying to classify if a book is fiction/nonfiction based on title and summary.

This is 2 distinct types of information - is there a way to segment `title` and `summary` before feeding it to a model, rather than concatenating the information?

**For example:**

Title: `"such a long journey"`

Summary: `"it is bombay in 1971, the year india went to..."`

Label: `"fiction"` (where fiction =1)

**Current procedure:**

What I've been doing until now is concatenating the information, so the above becomes,

```
example = "such a long journey it is bombay in 1971, the year india went to..."
label = 1
```

Then the usual setup, something like,

```
X.append(example)
y.append(label)
...
X = lemmatize(X)
...
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = split_data(X,y)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(...)
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

But feeding the data concatenated feels intuitively wrong. Is there a better way to do this?

If for some reason its possible with a library other than sklearn (keras, tensorflow) I'd be also open to hearing about that.

---

### UPDATE

Going from,

```
X = ['two'],['two'],['four'],['two'],['four'],['four']]
y = ['human','human','dog','human','dog','dog']
```

to,

```
X = [['two','hello'],['two','hello'],['four','bark'],['two','hi'],['four','bark'],['four','woof']]
y = ['human','human','dog','human','dog','dog']
```

causes errors to be thrown.

`'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` is X is a list, and `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'` if X is an array.

The error is thrown when I call,

```
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Is it possible to pass in a vector of features?

Comment: There's no reason to concatenate; pretty much any scikit-learn algorithm handles vector features.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I've updated my question.

Comment: Try creating a model.with multiple inputs and then merge them after few layers

Answer (score 1):

You could just apply two independent vectorization steps on your input `X` (one vectorizer for description and another for summary) and **then** concatenate the obtained feature matrices into a single feature matrix.

Doing it this way you will have features such as `description_"such", description_"long", ..., summary_"bombay", summary_"1971", ...`, so any model you apply will be able to:

1. Use all the features from the description and summary altogether
2. Give a different weight to desctiption tokens and summary tokens

Answer (score 0):

In **neural network**, it is possible to [**create a model with multiple inputs**](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models). Rather than concatenating, you can **create separate input** for the title and another for the summary where the input size of the title is smaller than that of the summary. In keras, you can do:

```
MAX_TITLE_LENGTH = 50
MAX_SUMMARY_LENGTH = 500
EMBEDDING_DIM = 50
CLASS_SIZE = 20

input_title = Input(shape=(MAX_TITLE_LENGTH,), name='input_title')
input_summary = Input(shape=(MAX_SUMMARY_LENGTH,), name='input_summary')

emb_title = Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_TITLE_LENGTH)(input_title)
emb_summary = Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_SUMMARY_LENGTH)(input_summary)

a = LSTM(128)(emb_title)
a = Dense(128, activation='relu')(a)

b = LSTM(512)(emb_summary)
b = Dense(128, activation='relu')(b)

z = Concatenate()([a, b])
z = Dense(128, activation='relu')(z)
output = Dense(CLASS_SIZE, activation='softmax')(z)

model = Model(inputs=[input_title , input_summary], outputs=output)
```

---

Also, regarding your error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Are you perhaps trying to convert the string in a list to lowercase? If so, check your code. It's trying to convert the list rather than the string, thus, giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is because the input you pass to vectorizer is a list of lists (or array of arrays), while, as stated in the [TfidfVectorizer syntax](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) you should pass a sequence of strings